# GAE runs commented out cron task?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, cron, google-cloud-platform

The project I am currently a part of hosts its application on GAE. Late last night I deployed our app to the QA server(also hosted on GAE) with a cron.yaml that had a commented out cron job.

The cron task was run as soon the deploy finished. Are there any explanations for this?

Below is the related cron.yaml and logs. We only have one qa backend instance at any given time.

Our stack is flask/python and angular frontend. My machine: macOS Sierra 10.12.1, GAE init v.4.0.1

cron.yaml:
[image]

log:
[image]

gulpfile:
        `

```
var $, gulp, minimist;

gulp      = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));
minimist  = require('minimist');
$         = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('deploy', 'Deploy project to Google App Engine.', function() {
  var k, options, options_str;
  options = minimist(process.argv);
  delete options['_'];
  options_str = '--skip_sdk_update_check';
  for (k in options) {
    if (options[k] === true) {
      options[k] = '';
    }
    options_str += k.length > 1 ? " --" + k + " " + options[k] : " -" + k + " " + options[k];
  }
  return gulp.src('run.py').pipe($.start([{
    match: /run.py$/,
    cmd: "appcfg.py update main " + options_str
  }]));
});

gulp.task('server', 'Start the local server. Available options:\n -o 
HOST  - the host to start the dev_appserver.py\n -p PORT  - the port 
to start the dev_appserver.py\n -a="..." - all following args are 
passed to dev_appserver.py\n', function() {
  var argv, k, known_options, options, options_str;
  argv = process.argv.slice(2);
  known_options = {
    "default": {
      p: '',
      o: '',
      a: ''
    }
  };
  options = minimist(argv, known_options);
  options_str = '-s';
  for (k in known_options["default"]) {
    if (options[k]) {
      if (k === 'a') {
        options_str += " --appserver-args \"" + options[k] + "\"";
      } else {
        options_str += " -" + k + " " + options[k];
      }
    }
  }
   return gulp.src('run.py').pipe($.start([
     {
      match: /run.py$/,
      cmd: "python run.py " + options_str
    }
  ]));
});
```

`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the cron job in the developer console? Did you have the cron enabled before that deployment?

Comment: It does not appear in console,  and I did not have it enabled when I deployed.

Comment: Is it possible that it was a manual request for that URL?

Comment: The payload indicates the request was from cron.

Comment: How did you deploy?

Comment: We deploy using gulp, building the frontend end(npm run build) then gulp deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a flyer here as I don't know what your gulp task looks like, but I suspect that it is issuing the following deployment command:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml
```

which does not update indexes or cron jobs (ie: does not reference the files cron.yaml or index.yaml).

Instead you will need to update the task to use:

```
appcfg.py update .
```

which will then do the necessary. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments).

Note: It may be preferable to use gcloud these days:

```
gcloud app deploy ...
```

Comment: That is called nowhere in our gulpfile.

Comment: Can you add the gulpfile to the question?

Comment: Added the gulpfile

Comment: Great; you are calling "appcfg.py update main"; so the next question is: which yaml files are in your "main" directory and where is your "cron.yaml" file situated? If cron.yaml is not in main then it is not being deployed by this gulp task.

Comment: It is in main with the rest of the yamls

Comment: Ok - then that should not be the problem. Have you done an explicit appcfg.py update main/cron.yaml and checked for any errors?